# Continue linenumbering between sections in reledmac + reledpar

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

I am helping my girlfrien with her thesis (a commented edition and translation of an old occitan poem). The main portion of the work is the critical edition: a chapter in which she divided the poem's stanzas in groups, which she comments separately (a `\section` for each group). Moreover, for each group of stanzas a translation is provided, so the entire text is compiled through the use of reledpar.

I would need for the numbering to be independend between the two parallel versions (automatic thanks to reledpar) but to continue across sections. In the example below, the linenumber of the verses of the second stanza (which is in a new section) should be 3 and 4.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[series={A},nofamiliar,noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\sethangingsymbol{[\,}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,1}
\AtEveryStopStanza{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Critical Edition}
General comment

\section{Stanza 1}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \stanza
    text in occitan & %verse 1
    second verse \& %verse 2

    \endnumbering 
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \stanza
    Translation first verse & %verse 1R
    Translation second verse \& %verse 2R
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\section{Stanza 2}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \stanza
    text in occitan & %verse 3
    second verse \& %verse 4

    \endnumbering 
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \stanza
    Translation first verse & %verse 3R
    Translation second verse \& %verse 4R
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

If this question is explained somewhere in the documentation I'm sorry, but I have missed it (or misinterpretated something)!

Thank you in advance, this is great help!

Comment: not directly in the handbook, but I will explain you tomorrow how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\pausenumbering`... `\resumenumbering`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[series={A},nofamiliar,noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\sethangingsymbol{[\,}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,1}
\AtEveryStopStanza{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Critical Edition}
General comment

\section{Stanza 1}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \stanza
    text in occitan & %verse 1
    second verse \& %verse 2

    \pausenumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \stanza
    Translation first verse & %verse 1R
    Translation second verse \& %verse 2R
    \pausenumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\section{Stanza 2}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \resumenumbering

    \stanza
    text in occitan & %verse 3
    second verse \& %verse 4

    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \resumenumbering
    \stanza
    Translation first verse & %verse 3R
    Translation second verse \& %verse 4R
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```