# Problem with highly asymmetric critical notes between two facing pages

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I am still formatting the thesis of my girlfriend, as per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557520/202311) question!

Now, for reasons that are beyond my comprehension (I am a statistician, I know nothing about critical editions) she uses very few notes on the left page (the occitan text) and a *lot* of those in the right one.

Is it possible to let the notes on the right page to flow also to the left one? (or viceversa, in general: notes defined on the left page to flow to the right one).

I hope the question is clear, I'm not sure how to clarify it better!

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nofamiliar,noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\sethangingsymbol{[\,}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,1}
\AtEveryStopStanza{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Critical Edition}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Stanza 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \stanza
    \edtext{text}{\Afootnote{Short note}} in occitan & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse \& 

    \endnumbering 
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \stanza
    \edtext{Translation}{\Bfootnote{Very long note: \lipsum[4-6]}} first verse & 
    \edtext{Other}{\Bfootnote{And also another long one: \lipsum[7-9]}} verse &
    \edtext{other}{\Bfootnote{Aaand the third one: \lipsum[10-11]}} verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse & 
    other verse \&
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

for now, I didnt find any algorithm able to do it automatically (and every if I did, I have no time anymore for big devellopement on reledmac/reledpar). However, you can do it manually, using `\edtextlater` and `\edtextnow`(§ 6.4 of reledpar handbook).